# mysql - multiple CASE statements for multiple columns with relevance (matching rank) of whatsoever value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

This is a search inside multiple columns in a MySQL table  with multiple keywords.

```
$query="select *
      ,case when prod_name like '%$search%' then 1 else 0 end as name_rank
      , case when prod_code like '%$search%' then 1 else 0 end as code_rank
      , case when prod_brand like '%$search%' then 1 else 0 end as brand_rank

      from products

      where prod_name like '%$search%'
      or prod_code like '%$search%'
      or prod_brand like '%$search%'

      order by (name_rank + code_rank + brand_rank ) desc";
```

When the search keywords (i.e: `prod 123`) are given as input in the search form, the landing URL becomes : `http://localhost/shop/index/search?search=prod+123`.

I get the query parameter in the following way :

```
$search=$_GET['search'];
```

Then the above query returns rows for which any single column contains both keywords. For example if column `prod_name` has `fine prod` and column `prod_brand` has '123', the query won't return this row.

1) Obviously I need to return that row as well

Again, when the search keyword is a single word i.e: `prod`  and  row 1 has  `product new` in `prod_name` column and row 2 has only `prod` in the same column, then row 2 should come before row 1 in results. Shouldn't it? I think unlike the query, it needs to detect any relevance in between 0 and 1

2) How to make the results reflect  this relevance or priority as well ?

I am using PHP (i.e. CodeIgniter framework) by the way.

How to achieve both points 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Investigate MySQL full text search:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, full text search will not find `nice product` for the keyword `prod`, right ?

Comment: It would using reasonable search engines that allow a thesaurus or keyword expansions.  If this is the main functionality you need, perhaps you should look into elastic search or a similar technology.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, not possible in MySQL ?

Comment: Use Latest version of MySQL (MySQL 5.6). Its support `full text indexing` and search http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @RejoanulAlam . . . I still don't think MySQL supports a thesaurus or word expansion in queries.

Comment: @RejoanulAlam, the OP asks for a partial match search clearly - see point 1. Full text search will not meet the requirement , right ?

Comment: Then you can use `sphinx` search engine which has some powerful options to modify your search criteria, even meet your no 1 requirements. http://sphinxsearch.com/